# solr 3.1 - where to download

Tags: apache, lucene, solr

I wanted to download solr 3.1 but the links from solr's official site are not working:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage#solr_development

any ideas ?

cheers,
/Marcin

Comment: solr 3.1??? 1.4 the latest from http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/apache//lucene/solr/

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr3.1 - Solr 3.1 has not been released

Comment: Technically not a programming question, and likely too localised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.1 Release: http://lucene.apache.org/#31+March+2011+-+Lucene+Core+3.1+and+Solr+3.1+Available
Download: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/lucene/solr/

Comment: That link no longer works....

Comment: Looks like the links need an update again. Or is this question to localized?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the correct link in here:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/3.1.0/

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the 3x branch from SVN:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/branch_3x/

Comment: This link is also not working anymore.

Comment: Solr 3.1 is now outdated. The latest stable release (3.6.1 as of this writing) can be found on http://lucene.apache.org/solr/downloads.html

Comment: This link doesn't work